# ¿Como agregar una tabla de forma dinamica con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estoy tratando de agregar una tabla en la que encierre los inputs que muestro a continuacion, los headers esos son estaticos pero igual no he podido agregarlos de forma exitosa ya que si creo la tabla el boton de eliminar deja de funcionar, caba aclarar que este boton fue diseñado para eliminar un solo input y me gustaria que funcionara y eliminara todos mis campos fila por fila:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".container1");
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="parametros[]"/> <input type="text" name="unidad[]"/> <input type="text" name="especificacion[]"/> <input type="text" name="resultado[]"/> <a href="#" class="delete">Eliminar</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
  else {
     alert('You Reached the limits')
  }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
<button class="add_form_field">Agregar malla o fondo &  nbsp; 
<span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span>
</button>

<table class="table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>PÁRAMETRO</th>
    <th>UNIDAD</th> 
    <th>ESPECIFICACIÓN</th>
    <th>RESULTADO</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: tienes un código funcional, aclárame esto, lo que quieres es hacer lo mismo pero en una tabla??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si buscas hacer eso en una tabla el código seria lo siguiente:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#masfilas").click(function(){
        $("#mytable").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="parametros[]"/></td><td> <input type="text" name="unidad[]"/></td><td> <input type="text" name="especificacion[]"/></td><td> <input type="text" name="resultado[]"/></td><td> <a href="#" class="delete">Eliminar</a></td></tr>');
        $('.delete').off().click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
<button id="masfilas" class="add_form_field">Agregar malla o fondo &  nbsp; 
<span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span>
</button>

<table id="mytable" class="table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>PÁRAMETRO</th>
    <th>UNIDAD</th> 
    <th>ESPECIFICACIÓN</th>
    <th>RESULTADO</th>
    <th>opciones</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu codigo funciona excelente pero no entiendo porque cuando lo aplique a mi sistema queria hacer un submit al agregar nuevos inputs

Comment: Falta el preventdefault talvez.

Comment: Pues no lo sé, tendriamos que el codigo no.

Answer (score 2):

Según lo que entiendo de tu publicacion, debemos crear los registros en la tabla (osea `<tr>`) luego el boton eliminar debe eliminar toda la fila (`<tr>`):

Creas tus filas `<tr>` en lugar del `<div>`:

```
$(wrapper).children('table').append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="parametros[]"/></td><td><input type="text" name="unidad[]"/></td><td><input type="text" name="especificacion[]"/><td></td><input type="text" name="resultado[]"/><td></td><td><a href="#" class="delete">Eliminar</a></<td></tr>'); //add input box
```

Luego ajustas el método de eliminar para que use el `<tr>` el lugar del `<div>`:

```
$(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); x--;
})
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvio tu codigo